# array[@] output all messed up?

Tags: bash, text-processing, newlines, array

I've got this code:

```
Unix+=("Stock List")
while read line; do 
  result=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$line&f=sl1&e=.csv" | tr ',' '    ' | tr '"' ' ')
  Unix+=("$result")
done < stock.txt

echo ${Unix[@]}
echo ${Unix[0]}
echo ${Unix[1]}
echo ${Unix[2]}
```

that reads a text file with only these lines in it:

```
SXX.L
QPP.L
```

And outputs this:

```
 QPP.L 14.2495.L 27.50
Stock List
SXX.L 27.50
QPP.L 14.2495
```

Why is the `array[@]` output missing information and messed up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executing with #!/bin/bash -x shows:

```
+ echo Stock List SXX.L $'27.50\r' QPP.L $'14.2495\r'
```

Those \r will likely be what's messing up the output. It moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, and whatever follows afterward overwrites what's already there.

Comment: Good find; confirmed that stripping out the `\r` characters fixes it

Comment: Thanks! I've added stripping the \r bits out, and as MM says, it fixes it!